# How to Set Meta description login page

Tags: customer, login, meta

I was woundering if any could help me find a way to set the Meta description for the **customer/account/login** page?

Cant find an xml file where I can change it and not sure how to do it in the login.phtml file.

Comment: Let us know which version of Magento you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Add code in the below xml file:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
```

find following code arround line no. 84 : `<customer_account_login translate="label">`

add below code in this block:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>YOUR META TITLE HERE</title></action>
    <action method="setDescription" translate="description" module="customer"><description>YOUR META DESCRIPTION HERE</description></action>
    <action method="setKeywords" translate="keywords" module="customer"><keywords>YOUR META KEYWORDS HERE</keywords></action>
</reference>
```

After add your code it will display like below:

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>YOUR META TITLE HERE</title></action>
        <action method="setDescription" translate="description" module="customer"><description>YOUR META DESCRIPTION HERE</description></action>
        <action method="setKeywords" translate="keywords" module="customer"><keywords>YOUR META KEYWORDS HERE</keywords></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create customer_account_login.xml layout file in to your theme or extension.
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml`

Add below code in created file.

```
<head>
 <meta name="description" content="Add description here"/>
</head>
```