# Location of some standard Magento pages

Tags: magento-1.9, meta

So I am running a `Magento 1.x` platform for an organization which is heavily focused on the organic indexation for google.

Our site audit tool is telling me that the following pages have a duplicate Meta descriptions

> - www.site.com/customer/account/login
> - www.site.com/checkout/cart
> - www.site.com/customer/account/forgotpassword

These pages clearly aren't CMS pages so I was already looking in the root folder on my FTP browser if I could find some phtml files that I could fill in the meta descriptions.

I haven't found the files yet so here's my question:

**1: In which folders would these be located?**

2: Should I do it this way or would there be another method of adjusting to the CMS?

**Note: This is a Magento 1.9 installation with a Wordpress integration**

Answer (score 3):

Regarding this you can Enable Default Magento feature called **Path Hints**.

To Enable this you can check below guidelines.

> 1. Log into the magento back-end admin.
> 2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
> 3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
> 4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
> 5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path
>      hints.

After follow Above steps dont forge to clear cache. Check [Here](https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/23/How-To-Clear-The-Magento-Cache)

After Enabling path hints you will get file path on your browser.

If it helps you to resolve your problem, Give up vote and accept answer to help other members..!!

Comment: Thank you for replying in such a fast timespan!  I followed the steps but it shows me site.com/customer/account/login/    which it already did.

i have a copy of the entire FTP on my desktop and was searching in that as well. i think I found it here:
app\design\frontend\rwd\geluk\template\customer\form

Comment: You need to change meta description ? , Correct me if i wrong.

Comment: Yes, somehow these three pages have the same meta description so I'm looking to change these inside the phtml files. if you have a method where I can adjust this inside the Admin panel that'd be preferable

Comment: Magento doesn't provide any option to update this pages meta details. You need to write your own module and update the meta details according to your requirement.

Comment: @DaveKoekebacker, There's solution but it's devloper friendly as Sukumar suggested , And i think you are not developer. You can change as mentioned here.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180164/set-meta-description-login-page

Comment: I'm not a developer no, i know the basics but that's where my knowledge ends regarding developing. But this XML file looks easy enough. thank you for the reference!